# DropShadowExtender in ie9

Tags: ajax

I have a very wierd problem and I dont know where to begin to fix it. I have tried my website on 8 computers using IE9 and for 2 of them the page doesnt show the correctly. I found out that when I take out the dropshadowextender it looks ok. So what I did is first try to go in  cleared out all cookies, etc.. and then went into advanced settings to compare the ones that were working to the ones that were not, but that didnt work. I tried the site on all machines using FireFox on all computers and they work fine. My problem is what could it be causing those 2 computers to not show up correctly. I could see if it showed up wrong when I ran the site on all computers.

Answer (score 0):

[CSS3 Pie](http://css3pie.com/) is a .htc file that, when placed on your server, provides extra code for IE so it can render many CSS3 styles on IE9, 8 and 7 properly.

Works well. Worth checking out.